# Bash: Passing parameters into environments of specific commands

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, parameter-passing

I know I can pass parameters directly into the environment like so:

`parameter=value command`

However it doesn't work in the case below, as I would expect it:

```
func()
{ 
    for char in a b c
    do
        echo $char
    done
}

while IFS= read line
do
    echo "char: $line"
done <<< $(func)
```

This has the output:

```
char: a b c
```

Once I do this:

```
IFS=
while read line
do
    echo "char: $line"
done <<< $(func)
```

It works just fine. The output is:

```
char: a
char: b
char: c
```

However then I have to reset my `IFS` parameter, which I would like to circumvent. And I'd like to know the reason behind this.

I use `GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0)`

Comment: double quote command sub e.g `"$(func)"` and don't change IFS at all.

Comment: Wow, that is stupidly easy. Thank you very much. And I understand why it works, but I'd still very much like to understand, why `IFS= read` doesn't work. Do you have an idea?

Comment: The IFS is limited to the loop and doesn't affect the < $(func), therefore read reads the full line. In the second example the IFS change is not limited to the loop and so affects the < $(func).

Comment: Ok, makes sense, thank you

Comment: `IFS` isn't really needed here at all if you echo $line piped to `sed`

Comment: I don't understand, what is `sed` supposed to do?

Comment: It can basically do what `IFS` does by manipulating the output of $line... the results may depend though on your version of bash. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1fcd1a8fd04fa47a0dd5

Comment: I'm not sure if the explanation @123 gave, is the correct one in your concrete example. `PAR=VAL CMD` sets the variable PAR in the environment for the child process CMD. In your case, you don't have a child process - `read` is an internal command of the shell. BTW, `IFS` is a (non-exported) shell variable. You could export it, but it is bad style: It would affect also child processes invoked from the CMD you are calling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in the upcoming 4.4 release of `bash`.

```
bash-4.4$ func()
> {
>     for char in a b c
>     do
>         echo $char
>     done
> }
bash-4.4$
bash-4.4$ while IFS= read line
> do
>     echo "char: $line"
> done <<< $(func)
char: a
char: b
char: c
```

Making here strings work properly (i.e., as documented) is a bit of an on-going process.

Comment: Wow, I'm kind of proud of myself to have discovered a bug in bash, thank you very much!